# HighCharts: Adding onClick callback on stackLables for a stacked bar chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Goal is to add a button in front of each stacked bar and click on the button for drilldown charts.

I have added button as stackLabel and stuck while adding onClick callback to it.

```
yAxis:{
                        stackLabels:{
                            enabled:true,
                            formatter: function(){
                                return '>'; /* this will be replaced to button*/
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Do we have any better way to achieve this?

Please check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyzfa0b4/6/

Comment: To render a button you can [renderer.button](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.button), see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fyzfa0b4/7/). I cannot see any drilldowns in your charts.

Comment: Thanks @morganfree for your help. I am using below renderer to render buttons at the same position where stackLabels appear :                              ` this.renderer.button('>',this.plotWidth + 30 , this.xAxis[0].top, function () {}`                                                                                                         Is there any better to position them like stackLabels?

Comment: Is there any better way to align renderer buttons similar to stackLabel position ?

Comment: You can use point.shapeArgs properties (x, y, height, width) or point.plotX/plotY to have point's coordinates.